# Make Gmail/Google Apps not mark wrong emails as spam

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-forwarding

I have a site and I set all emails to go to a specific account if the email doesn't exist. This way I can have support, webmaster, and anything else go to `wrongemail` account. `wrongemail` and `admin` both forward emails to my personal email so I don't need to check multiple accounts.

Problem is when I email webmaster@mysite.com it goes to `wrongemail` BUT `wrongemail` doesn't forward it to me and is marked as spam. At the moment I'd rather nothing be marked as spam.

How do I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a filter. Write `*`. Hit next, have it 'never send to spam'. Optionally you can have it forward if everything isnt being forward already (dont worry. it will say it is not allowed in this case). Everything should work flawlessly and attachments do also forward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "teach" gmail which emails are spam and which are not. If you "un-spam" a few of the emails that you want, it will get the idea.

Alternatively you could set up a rule in the "filters" and set the "do not send to spam" option.